Keep or remove the request for address?
I'm struggling at selling event tickets online through my own website and I think the #1 reason is I'm asking for too much info.
Specifically, I'm asking for customer's full name and email and the same info for all the people the customer is buying for. Then I ask for the customer's full address.
Here's what I found out.
When I used a 3rd-party website exclusively to sell event tickets in the past, I had more success. I noticed on their checkout form, they accept google pay and credit card. They don't give people an option to enter their address.
But when I do it through my site, I ask for the address and indicate that its optional but it increases the odds of a transaction to be successful (since the customer's bank verifies the info).
How am I supposed to work this on the user experience side so I can drive more customers to my site to buy tickets?
Should I just eliminate the address fields and only show them if the transaction failed?
Should I leave the address fields on?
Should I only have the address fields shown if a user clicks a button to activate them?
What do I do?

Perhaps you can use a third-party payment processor and let them worry about the transaction success? Why not use whatever was used on the other event website you used?
Speaking as a customer, I'm rarely surprised at being asked for an address by a website these days, even if the thing I'm buying has no physical dimension — unless of course I click away to pay through Paypal, which already has those details in my account.
On the other hand, I buy sets of tickets fairly often and I can't think of the last time I was asked to identify even one person they were for, let alone all. Sometimes I buy a class set of 20 or 25 and that would be a huge pain, plus I may not even know the email address of each and every person. And then if someone couldn't come I wouldn't be able to give their ticket to someone else, so it would be wasted. This would definitely make me second-guess the purchase.
One feature that could be relevant, though, is a checkbox or other page saying "Send a copy of the tickets to someone else?" with the chance to enter their email address. This might save me time waiting for your site to send me my tickets and then having to forward it myself. I've used something like that sometimes when buying for my family and someone else's, and then I'll enter just one email address of someone from that family since they'll likely come to the event together.

My business is speed dating so when I sell tickets I'd like to have the basic info (name and email address) up front so I don't have to ask them such information later. Then it will ensure only the correct people attend the event. I'm already using the Square payment processor and the part they control is the input going into the credit card fields. On the other site, it lacks colour. I already removed some text boxes though to be more in line with that site.

@mike_s Interesting and sounds more complicated than your average ticket sales.

@mike_s That comment should be added to the question. It's necessary information about why you're asking for the data.
